# How to add a force pulling some vertices of a cloth?

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I have a simple cloth simulation of a triangular sail set up, with the vertical edge marked as a pin group. Now I would like the vertex on the right of the triangle to not just be pinned, but to be actively pulling the sail in a direction, as indicated by the red arrow. I want the sail to crease as if a force was applied to the corner.

[image]

Another example of the same situation is a rectangular bedsheeet being pulled on all four corners at the same time by two people folding it: I can simulate a cloth hanging by the four corners as in the image below, but a cloth that's being pulled by the four corners would crease differently and not sag as much.

[image]

I suppose I need to add a force field of some kind, but I'm quite new to physics simulations in blender and I haven't been able to figure it out.

What is the correct way to add some forces pulling on (specific parts of) a cloth object?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "pulling the sail in a direction"? Maybe show a drawing or a storyboard?

Comment: @moonboots I added an arrow to the drawing. Basically I want the cloth to crease as if it's being pulled in a direction. Another example would be a rectangular bedsheet being pulled on all 4 corners at the same time to straighten it a bit by two persons that are folding it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your sail, assign the vertices on the right and on the left to the same group. Give your sail a cloth simulation, choose the group as *Pin Group*. Select the vertices on the right and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to New Object* (which will create a new empty at the same position). Put the *Hook* modifier above the *Cloth* modifier:

[image]

Result if you animate the empty:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm very much a beginner, how are you animating the empty object?

Comment: This is basic animation, open the Timeline window, select the empty in the 3D view and press "i" to create a location keyframe, move the blue playerhead of the Timeline a bit further, press "i" to create a second keyframe